# Try to create video with 2 overlays

Tags: filter, ffmpeg, overlay

Could someone tell me what is wrong with this command. Basically I create a video with 2 overlays left and right. It keeps telling : unconnected output.

```
/Users/Marco/Documents/@Dev/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -report -i EM2022_LP01_BL01_P1.m4v -i EM2022_LP01_BL01_P2.m4v -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=5760x240[base]; [0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=2880x240[p1]; [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=2880x240[p2]; [base][p1]overlay=shortest=1:[base+p1]; [base+p1][p2]overlay=shortest=1:x=2880[base+p2]" led.m4v
```

I tried to use existing answers with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Found it: I added: -map "[base+p2]" -y led.m4v

And this works. Hope it might help somebody else.

Cheers,
Marco